# Authentication problem while connecting to WiFi hot spot!

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot

I just unboxed my androidOne device (Micromax Canvas A1) and while connnecting to my WiFi hotspot it loops through:

1. When entered the password, proxy etc: *Saved, secured with WPA2*
2. When tapped on connect: *Authenticating...*
3. and then: *Authentication Problem*

Note that my room-mates (and even I, with my other phone,) can use the hot spot.

Is this an indication of problem with device?

I tried:

```
1. Forgetting access points and resetting passwords.
2. restarting my phone several times
3. restarting my hotspot several times
4. factory resetting the phone once
```

nothing worked.

Comment: Try forgetting the network and putting the password in again.

Comment: @DanHulme ya ... I did it several times.. I even did a factory reset! still no success

Comment: If you don't want your and everyone else's time wasted with suggestions you've already tried, [edit] your question to say what hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing the default wifi driver that comes with windows with the one downloaded from manufacturer website.

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar problem since months on my Android phone ( Jellybean and Kitkat ). The problem some how used to come and go and recently it was the same again. After spending a couple of hours with many hit and try things with my phone and router I finally found a good article which solved this problem ( at least ) for me.

**Solution**

> Settings, Apps, All, Clear data in google services framework and restart
>   http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/45501-43-wifi-authentication-problem

Read the above article as it has a lot of other methods also but in my case none of the others worked. Check if anyone works in your case.

Before following above steps I would kindly request to go through the article about what things can be impacted when Google Services Framework data is cleared.

http://www.talkandroid.com/185088-google-engineer-explains-why-you-shouldnt-clear-google-services-framework-data/

In my case I have tried almost everything and nothing worked. Clearing the google services framework data was the last option left and I gave it a try. My case - it worked well and I did not even have to restart the phone, I was able to connect the WiFi.

Hope it helps.