# WiFi authentication problem

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering

I have got my android (Lenovo Vibe P1M) and for a couple of days my WiFi worked smoothly.But when i tried connecting it yesterday it says **authentication problem**.

While my family members can use the WiFi with their phones, I can't.

What I've tried so far:

```
1. turning my WiFi on in Airplane mode.
2. clearing data from google services framework.
3. going far away from my router and trying to connect. 
4. factory resetting the phone once
5. Forgetting access points and resetting passwords.
6. restarting my hotspot several times
7. restarting my phone several times
```

nothing worked.

**NOTE:** I see this question has been asked **before** [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/85785/authentication-problem-while-connecting-to-wifi-hot-spot) but that doesn't solve my problem.

Does it mean there is a problem with my device?

Comment: Is the clock correct? Authentication sometimes requires a synchronous clock. Try using the setting for automatic time set in the Date/Time setting panel.

Comment: @wbogacz  yes automatic time zone is activated.

Comment: Does you WiFi work on other devices

Comment: I think you missed the point of my question; or, I missed the point of your reply. TZ is certainly important, but I was asking whether the time itself is automatically set by your network. For the devices that connect properly, is their time the same as your device?

Comment: @doga Yes it works on other devices.I mentioned that in my post though.

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was a full memory - deleted Gigabytes of photos -> worked

Comment: How did you figure out that low storage was the cause of Wi-Fi authentication? Prima facie, it seems unlikely.

Comment: To be honest, if the disk is full this can cause all kind of problems and in my case I saw that the disk is full. After clearing up data it worked.